# How do you access IApplicationBuilder.Properties from controller in MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

The MVC 6 new ASP.net 5.0 web site project template contains a Startup.cs class with the below method. If I add a property to the IApplicationBuilder `app`, how do I access it later in my controller?

For example,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
{
    app.Properties.Add("foo", "bar");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best I can tell, you cannot access the builder's `Properties` bag directly once the app is running. The `Properties` bag is there for building the pipeline and not for maintaining application state.

If you need some app-specific state, I recommend registering your own service that can store data in the appropriate structure for your application. If you want, you could certainly write a service that grabs the builder's `Properties` bag and holds onto it for later use, but I would discourage this, as it wasn't "your" dictionary, and as such is unlikely to satisfy any guarantees about lifetime, etc.

Comment: I wrote an answer to a related question that may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26343378/3279

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to look for this option after read your question and it is partially possible but mainly what you have to do with that.

Instead of this I suggest that you should write your Owin Middleware for asp.net mvc 6 and put your property in HttpContext and later you can retrieve at controller level without any problem.