# Can I have different Dbcontext with asp.identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I have 3 web applications that are completely same projects but they are accessing 3 different databases, which has completely same struture. I want to create Api with OAuth and microsoft identity.
My question is - Can I have one project ( web api ) that can create 3 owin context for 3 different database so that I don't have to publish 3 completely same projects.

Comment: Does the app need to reference more than one of the databases at the same time, or can it be determined at startup which one to use?

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking exactly. I think I have to determine at startup all 3 context, but I think I will have problems with OAuth. I want all 3 apps to send requests to the same controllers, but based on their parameter, I will ask different database

Comment: So you're asking how to vary the `connectionString` based on some variable in the `http request`? And each request only uses *one* database?

Comment: Yes, but having in mind authorization for every request. Main problem is identity, if I didn't use identity I would create connection on every request with ADO ,but obviously I have to work with identity

Comment: Something like [this answer in "Setup OWIN dynamically"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25405782/43846)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can have multible databases, you just have to program the configuration for each case through connectionString.

MyDbContext :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring( DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder )
{
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer( "<Your Connection String Here>" );
}
```

Startup.ConfigureServices :

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    var configuration = new Configuration().AddJsonFile( "MyConfig.json" );
    services.AddEntityFramework( configuration )
    // ...
}
```

Another url on the topic that can help:

> https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/22654400/entity-framework-6-and-asp-net-identity-usermanager--multiple-dbcontext